# Sum of digits in Clojure

Tags: beginner, clojure

I wrote a simple program to sum the digits of a number in Clojure for learning purpose. Not very complex (I hope) so not adding any explanation. I am a beginner in Clojure so please don't mind pointing out even the most obvious mistakes.

**NOTE:** It recursively calculates the sum of digits in the result until a single digit result is obtained. For example, given "4312", 1 is returned (4312 -> 10 -> 1).

```clj
(defn sum-once [x]
  (reduce +
          (map
            #(Integer/parseInt (str %))
            (seq (char-array x)))))

(defn sum-digits [x]
  (let [y (sum-once x)]
    (if (< y 10) y
                 (sum-digits (str y)))))
```

Comment: @ferada What is the language tag that you used?

Comment: should it work - since `(sum-digits "4312")` gives 1

Comment: @birdspider Yeah it is supposed to work like that. Recursively till a single digit output is given. Added that in the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AseemBansal I marked it as Clojure, so if you click on `edit` you'll see `lang-clj` as the language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retaining your names, I'd rewrite the functions as follows:

```
(defn sum-once [x]
  (reduce +
          (map
            #(- (int %) (int \0))
            (str x))))

(defn sum-digits [x]
  (let [y (sum-once x)]
    (if (< y 10) 
      y
      (recur y))))
```

The only substantive change to [Casey's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/110565/43360) is to replace the recursive call of `sum-digits` with [`recur`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#recur). This recognises tail recursion and implements it by a *goto*: faster and not subject to stack overflow.

---

**Edit**

We can probably (untested) make things faster by calculating the digit sum inline:

```
(defn sum-digits [x]
  (let [y (loop [x (long x), ans 0]
            (if (zero? x)
              ans
              (recur (quot x 10) (+ ans (mod x 10)))))]
    (if (< y 10) 
      y
      (recur y))))
```

This avoids layers of sequence functions and the boxing and unboxing that goes with calling global functions.

- There is no conversion to and from characters.
- We get the digits right to left.
- The `(long x)` conversion is a hint enabling the compiler to infer
  that everything    is a `long`.

---

By the way, you can get the same result from the remainder of dividing the original number by 9, except that 0 translates to 9, unless the original number was zero:

```
(defn sum-digits [n]
  (if (zero? n)
    0
    (let [r (mod n 9)]
      (if (zero? r) 9 r))))
```

Comment: _boxing and unboxing that goes with calling global_. Could you elaborate that a bit?

Comment: @AseemBansal Arguments are passed to and the result returned from Clojure functions as Java `Object`s. This is evident in the `invoke` methods of [`clojure.core.IFn`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java). So numbers such as `long`s have to be passed as `Object`s such as `Long`s.

Answer (score 3):

I was confused by your code until reading the comments. You want to change the name of `sum-once` to `sum-digits` or `digit-sum` (pick this one!) or anything like it, since that's what it really does.

Your current `sum-digits` should become `digital-root` (that's [the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) for what you're trying to achieve).

> The digital root (also repeated digital sum) of a non-negative integer
>   is the (single digit) value obtained by an iterative process of
>   summing digits, on each iteration using the result from the previous
>   iteration to compute a digit sum. The process continues until a
>   single-digit number is reached.

Answer (score 2):

Stylistically this is pretty good. I have two stylistic suggestions, plus a bit of code-golf:

1. Stylistically, I would prefer for `sum-once` to take a number and call `str` there. Also, there are a few standards around "subsidiary" functions - I prefer a "-" prefix. So it would be `sum-digits` and `-sum-digits`.
2. You don't need to convert a string to a `char-array` - it is already a sequence.

   ```
   user=> (seq "4312")
   (\4 \3 \1 \2)
   ```
3. This is total code-golf, but you can just subtract individual characters from the ASCII value of 0, which happens to be 48:

   ```
   (defn -sum-digits
     [val]
     (reduce + 
             (map #(- (int %) 48) 
                  (str val))))
   ```

Comment: In (3), replace magic number `48` with self-explanatory `(int \0)`?